# Menubar with Storyboard - validateMenuItem not get called

Tags: swift, macos, delegates, menubar

I'm trying to setup a menubar Application using storyboard but my `validateMenuItem` method not get called.

I will try to explain what i did.
First i dragged a Menu Item in my Application Scene. Then one Object for my MenuController. Created a MenuController (MenuController.swift) and filled it with code. Back in my storyboard I set my Menu delegate to MenuController and MenuController Outlet to Menu. (I'm not totally sure whether i have set the delegates correctly.)

When i start the app, the menu icon appears and the first item title is set to test. But when i'm clicking the icon the `validateMenuItem` method not get called.

MenuController.swift

```
import Cocoa
class MenuController: NSObject {

    var statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(-1)

    @IBOutlet weak var statusMenu: NSMenu!
    @IBOutlet weak var item1: NSMenuItem!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        print("awakeFromNib")

        self.item1.title = "Test"

        let icon = NSImage(named: "menubarIcon")
        statusItem.image = icon
        statusItem.menu = statusMenu
    }

    override func validateMenuItem(menuItem: NSMenuItem) -> Bool {
        print("validateMenuItem")
        return true
    }
}
```

Storyboard Menu Delegates
[image: Storyboard Menu Delegates]
<sub>(source: [picr.de](http://up.picr.de/23648472pu.jpg))</sub>

Storyboard MenuController Delegates
[image: Storyboard MenuController Delegates]
<sub>(source: [picr.de](http://up.picr.de/23648473df.jpg))</sub>

Has anybody an idea?

Greets from Austria!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The menu/UI validation mechanism does not query the menu's delegate but uses the item's target to determine the enabled state instead.
If the target is not explicitly  set, it walks the responder chain.

To get basic validation, you have to make sure that the following things are setup:

- "Auto Enables Items" is checked in Interface Builder (on by default)
- You control-dragged the menu's action to the first responder
- The menu's action is implemented in a class that is part of the responder chain (e.g. a view controller that manages a set of actions for your UI)

A basic implementation of `validateUserInterfaceItem:` could look like the following for an item with an action selector called test:

```
func validateUserInterfaceItem(anItem: NSValidatedUserInterfaceItem) -> Bool
{
    if anItem.action() == Selector("test:") {
        print("validating item \(anItem)")
        return true
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: I've forgotten to connect an action. Now it works. Thank you!!

Comment: NB: The class which implements the action and `validateUserInterfaceItem(:)` also needs to include `NSUserInterfaceValidations` in the protocol/inheritance list. If it doesn't, the validation method won't be called.

Comment: this was objc magic, in swift there is not introspection, so you have to TELL the runtime, it keeps biting me, i use NSMenuDelegate, NSMenuItemValidation for all my right click context menus

Comment: Mmh, not working for an action method defined in the AppDelegate

Comment: Oh, nevermind. Forgot to mark `validateUserInterfaceItem` as `@objc`. Now it works!